# Getting unrecognizable words while finding Trigrams from NLTK Collocations

Tags: python, nltk, collocation

I am using NLTK Collocations to find trigrams and '**training_set**' is a string with many lines of text.

```
 finder = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(str(training_set))
 print finder.nbest(trigram_measures.pmi, 5)
```

But I am getting the output as

```
 [('\xe5', '\x8d', '\xb8'), ('\xe5', '\x85', '\x8d'), ('\xe2', '\x80', '\x9c'), ('\xe2',    '\x80', '\x9d'), ('\xe2', '\x80', '\xa6')]
```

Is this some encoding problem? How do I get normal english words?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those look like 'windows-1252' encoded characters:

```
>>> import chardet

>>> chardet.detect('\xe5') {'confidence': 0.5, 'encoding': 'windows-1252'}
```

So if you don't want those to show up you can do something like this to your text:

```
>> '\xe5'.decode('windows-1252').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: Running the decoding and encoding script is giving an empty string.

Comment: Well they won't be english word's because they're foreign characters. Just omit the encode portion to get the the actual letters. >>> print '\xe5'.decode('windows-1252')
å . It also looks like what you have aren't trigrams of words but of individual letters. You likely have to to tokenize your text before sending it to the TrigramCollocationFinder.

Comment: finder =TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(nltk.word_tokenize(str(training_set)))